# Separating set system

Tags: combinatorics

Let $[n]$ denote the integers from 1 to n.  I'm interested in a family of subsets $\{C_k\}$ such that for all $i \neq j$ there exists a set $C_k$ such that either $i \in C_k$ and $j \notin C_k$ or $j \in C_k$ and $i \notin C_k$.  Does anyone know what such a subset system is called?  Also, what are the known bounds on the size of this family?

Comment: It might be helpful to think of this as a directed graph on vertices $\{1,2,\dots,n\}$ where $C_k$ is the vertices that $k$ leads to.

Comment: The minimum size of such a family is $\left\lceil\frac{\log n}{\log2}\right\rceil$.

Comment: Can you explain?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we let $A_i$ denote the set of $t$ for which $S_t$ contains $i$, your statement is equivalent to the statement that no two $A_i$ are identical.  This gives the bound that $2^{|F|} \geq n$, meaning your family must have size at least $\lceil \log_2 n \rceil$ This bound is achievable, for example, by letting $S_i$ be the numbers with a $1$ in the $i^{th}$ bit when written in binary.

In the computer science literature, this property is referred to as the weak $2-$selector property.  More generally, a weak $k$ selector is a family of sets for which, given any subset of $k$ sets, we can find an element contained in exactly one set from the subset.  A strong selector would be similar, except now we want there to be an element unique to each of the $k$ sets in each subset of size $k$.  For $k=2$ (the analogue of your problem) a strong selector would be saying that for every $i \neq j$ we can find a set containing $i$ but not $j$ **and** a set containing $j$ but not $i$.

For $k=2$ strong selectors are dual to antichains, and Sperner’s Theorem gives the optimal size.

Comment: Thank you!  Do you have a reference that discusses weak/strong selectors?  I can't find any literature on line.

Comment: Clementi, Monti, and Silvestri's "Distributed broadcast in radio networks of unknown topology" (https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0304397502008514 ) discusses them and gives the (currently) best known bounds, along with some earlier papers (particularly the Chlebus, Gasieniec, Gibbons, Pelc, Rytter) that use the concept.

Comment: Strong Selectors go back to the work of Erdos, Frankl, and Furedi (Families of finite sets in which no set is covered by the union of $r$ others), albeit in a dual formulation: The sets in EFF can be thought of as "The set of all $j$ for which $C_j$ contains a particular element".